# Application of Fubini's Theorem

Tags: measure-theory, fourier-analysis

I am trying to show that for $f,g\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $f*g\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Somewhere along the way I need to switch the order of integration in the following integral (I know this for sure because it is literally a step out of my professor's notes).

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^{d}}f(x-y)g(y)e^{-i\xi\cdot x}\;dy\;dx.$$

In the notes it says "By Fubini's Theorem".  But I can't verify the hypothesis of the theorem which says the integrals may be switched if the following is true:

$f(\cdot-y)g(y)e^{-i\xi\cdot \cdot}$ and $f(x-\cdot)g(\cdot)e^{-i\xi\cdot x}$ are both in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: Hmm..  since $f$ and $g$ are bounded right?  I guess that would make this trivial...

Comment: If my previous comment is not mistaken, then I don't need an answer but just a confirmation would be correct.  I never trust my logic in Measure spaces. :P

Comment: Why would they be bounded?  Not all functions in $L_1$ are bounded.

Comment: Of course not.  $1/x^2$ is not bounded near $0$, and it is an $L_{1}$ function.  I don't know what I was thinking.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We want to think about $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)g(y)\;dy\right) e^{-i\xi\cdot x} \;dx.$$
The expression inside the parentheses is the convolution.  Suppose for now that we already know that $y \mapsto f(x-y)g(y)$ is in $L_1$.  The expression above is equal to
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)g(y)e^{-i\xi\cdot x}\;dy\right) \;dx
$$
(the factor $e^{-i\xi\cdot x}$ does not depend on $y$, so it is "constant").  Here we have an iterated integral.  Fubini's theorem says this is equal to the double integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d} f(x-y)g(y)e^{-i\xi\cdot x} (dy\;dx)
$$
if the latter exists.  Since $x$ and $\xi$ are real, the factor $e^{-i\xi\cdot x}$ has absolute value $1$.  Hence we have
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x-y)g(y)e^{-i\xi\cdot x}| (dy\;dx) =
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d\times\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x-y)g(y)| (dy\;dx).
$$
All we need now is that that last integral is finite.  If you've seen a theorem saying $L_1$ is closed under convolution, you've got it.

**Later note:** If $L_1$ is closed under convolution, that says
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |(f*g)(x)|\;dx < \infty,
$$
which is the same as saying that the iterated integral
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^d} |f(x-y)g(y)| \;dy\right)\;dx
$$
is finite.  That means where I wrote "...you've got it" above, you'd probably need to cite one more fact about integrals.

Comment: I'm so sorry for the major typo in my question! the result you mention is in fact what I was trying to prove:  that $f*g\in L_{1}(\mathbb{R^{d}})$.  But I still think I can use your explanation to answer my question!

Comment: This answer is evidence of the overall trend of *under*-voting on MSE...